# Android - how to open a push notification deep-link intent that, when closed, returns to the Home screen?

Tags: android, notifications, history, android-pendingintent

I've created a receiver to receive and display push notifications - when the user presses on the push notification it opens a deep-link within my application. The problem is that when the user presses "back" he doesn't exit back to the home screen, but rather he goes to whatever screens for my application were open before on the application backstack - even if the application was minimized before he pressed on the notification.

The behavior that I need is for the user to be on the home screen, for him to open the notifications panel, press on my notification, go into the deep link page in my app, and when he presses the back button - I want him to exit all the way out to the home screen again. I don't want him in any way interacting with the backstack for the main application.

I've tried numerous combinations of flags for the pendingIntent in the push notification. Everything from FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, etc. No combination seems to give me what I want - in every single case, opening the deep link with the app minimized will always return me to the next page in the history of the app when I press the back button. How can I solve this?

Example code:

```
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DeepLink.class);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1,       notificationIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The deeplink class was starting an intent for each deeplink and these required that I set the flags NEW_TASK and CLEAR_TASK for each one. After that - everything worked.